# R combine list items

Tags: r, list

I have a `R` list as following

```
mlist <- list(name = c('id','value'), type = c('bigint','float'))
```

I want to combine it in a way which I can end up with the following string

```
id bigint,value float
```

I searched but could not find a way to do that. Can someone let me know how can I do that without looping over rows, I want to be able to use something like `apply` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = c, unname(mlist)))
#$id
#[1] "id"     "bigint"

#$value
#[1] "value" "float"
```

If it needs to be a single string, use `paste`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = paste, unname(mlist)))
```

If we need to get a vector as output use `unlist`

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = paste, sep="_", unname(mlist))), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "id_bigint"   "value_float"
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
transpose(mlist) %>% 
     map(flatten_chr)
#[[1]]
#[1] "id"     "bigint"

#[[2]]
#[1] "value" "float"
```

Comment: thanks very much, but how can join the final result as an string, since it again has two rows

Comment: @MajidHojati  I have already updated with `paste` output `do.call(Map, c(f = paste, unname(mlist)))`  If you need to unlist, `unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = paste, unname(mlist))))`

Comment: thanks so much, yes I was looking for unlist, Is it possible to unlist and add a separator between list items?

Comment: thanks so much, But I want separator in this way `"id bigint",   "value float"`

Comment: @MajidHojati  You meant a single string insteed of two?

Comment: @MajidHojati May be you need `toString(unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = paste, unname(mlist))), use.names = FALSE))#
[1] "id bigint, value float"`

Comment: @MajidHojati  Then, the above comment should work for you

Answer (score 2):

With `purrr`, we can also do:

```
library(purrr)

toString(pmap(mlist, paste))
# [1] "id bigint, value float"
```

Another Base R approach:

```
toString(Reduce(function(x1, x2){
  mapply(function(x2, y2){
    paste(x2, y2, collapse = " ")
  }, x1, x2)
}, mlist))
# [1] "id bigint, value float"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @avid_useR

library(purrr)

pmap_chr(mlist, paste)